# nokogiri how to extract part of the field

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

My text file like:

```
<first>1</first><Name>wangli</Name><birthday>19860105</birthday><address>Here</address>
<first>2</first><Name>zhangli</Name><birthday>19870105</birthday><address>Sangdu</address>
<first>3</first><Name>lili</Name><birthday>19880105</birthday><address>Hongkong</address>
<first>4</first><Name>liuli</Name><birthday>19860515</birthday><address>London</address>
```

I want create a new file with ruby gem nokogiri like:

```
wangli-Here
zhangli-Sangdu
lili-Hongkong
liuli-London
```

I used:

```
require 'nokogiri'
doc = Nokogiri::XML(File.open("file"),nil,"gbk")
puts doc.xpath("/name") + doc.xpath("/address")
```

can't work

Comment: Check the Nokogiri cheatsheet: https://github.com/sparklemotion/nokogiri/wiki/Cheat-sheet

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Read "[ask]", "[mcve]" and http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/128421. Your code doesn't show your effort and looks like a minor attempt hoping we'll fill in the blanks.

Comment: Is your text file actually an XML document, or is it really a series of XML fragments? If it's the second how did it get that way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since each line of your input XML contains an XML fragment, you have to process each line one by one. Also, you need to use `Nokogiri::XML.fragment` to parse each line.  Here is working example:

```
require "nokogiri"

output = File.open("output.txt", "w")

File.open("input.xml", "r") do |f|
    f.each_line do |line|
        frag = Nokogiri::XML.fragment(line)
        output.puts "#{frag.search('Name').text}=#{frag.search('address').text}"
    end
end

output.close
```

Comment: Thank you lots. But how can I get Name.language GBK?

Comment: @Syutran I am not sure what `Name.langauge` mean, and what is `GBK`

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the problem solved!
I change the text file:

```
<doc>
<line><first>1</first><Name>wangli</Name><birthday>19860105</birthday><address>Here</address></line>
<line><first>2</first><Name>zhangli</Name><birthday>19870105</birthday><address>Sangdu</address></line>
<line><first>3</first><Name>lili</Name><birthday>19880105</birthday><address>Hongkong</address></line>
<line><first>4</first><Name>liuli</Name><birthday>19860515</birthday><address>London</address></line>
</doc>
```

and then the ruby code

```
require 'nokogiri'
doc = Nokogiri::XML(File.open("27065"),nil,"gbk")
doc.xpath("//line").each do |line|
    l.xpath("./name").text + "-" + line.xpath("./address").text
end
```

Comment: It's not necessary to modify the file at all. A better question is why is the file structured like that; It's not valid XML.